# Getting object form ObservableArray in Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have a service class that has a array of quests like so:

```
import { ObservableArray, ChangedData } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array';

quests: ObservableArray<Quest>;
```

I can push quests into the array like this:

```
let quest = new Quest(data.key, data.value["name"], data.value["description");
this.quests.push(quest);
```

In another class I subscribe to change events of that array:

```
this.myService.quests.on(ObservableArray.changeEvent,(args:ChangedData<Quest>) => {
    console.log(args.object);
    let quest: Quest = args.object; // can not cast to quest
});
```

In the log I can see that my data is inside the `ChangeData`. But I horribly fail to cast that back to my object.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `let quest = <Quest> args.object;` ?

Comment: Yes @DotNetDreamer I did

Comment: try the above and remove the typing from `(args:ChangedData<Quest>) =>` make it `(args) =>`

Comment: Nope, not working @DotNetDreamer

Comment: `args` if of type `EventData` its `object` property is of type element which raised the event. So you can't grab the `Quest` from its object. So you will be only notified by change detection. You can see this here https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a solution for you [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/observable-array). The problem is the typings. It doesn't show the properties that you need. So just make it of type `any` Essentially you need to do the following:

```
this.myService.quests.on(ObservableArray.changeEvent, (args: any) => {
  console.log(args.index);
  //the item which was added
  console.log(this.myService.quests.getItem(args.index));
  //now you can cast it
  let quest = <Quest>this.myService.quests.getItem(args.index);
  console.log(args.action); // Action (In this case "add")
});
```

When i tried to add a test object, i got this. Notice the index property. Using `index` you will get the newly added property.

```
this.myService.quests.push({ name: 'test1' });
this.myService.quests.push({ name: 'test2' });
```

And here was the output:

```
JS: 0 //this is index
JS: {
JS:   "name": "test1"
JS: }
JS: add //this is the action
JS: 1
JS: {
JS:   "name": "test2"
JS: }
JS: add
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I'll try this later!

Comment: @NicoS.glad it helped